# Unable to use urban airship and Facebook cloud messaging together in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I have been using urban airship in my iOS app and my backend for push notifications. Recently, I had to migrate my phone number authentication from digits to firebase which involved using Firebase Cloud messaging. Firebase Cloud messaging does not work until I comment out the setup of urban airship. Is there a way to use both? What might be causing the problem? I don't want to change my current push notification setup for this migration.

My AppDelegate currently looks like this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
        .setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIUtils.getFont(14)],
                                for: UIControlState())
    FirebaseApp.configure()
//        setupUrbanAirship()
    return true
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    // Pass device token to auth
    Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo) {
        completionHandler(.noData)
        return
    }
}
fileprivate func setupUrbanAirship() {
    let filename = PropertyUtils.getUAPropertyFileName()
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "plist")
    let config = UAConfig(contentsOfFile: path!)

    //config.automaticSetupEnabled = false
    UAirship.takeOff(config)
    let channelID = UAirship.push().channelID
    print("My Application Channel ID: \(channelID)")
    UAirship.push().userPushNotificationsEnabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had to use manual integration steps of urban airship and got their latest build updated in my app.